# Symbolism of Albus Dumbledore's name in Harry Potter

Tags: symbolism, name-significance, j-k-rowling, harry-potter

What is the symbolism of the name Albus Dumbledore in Harry Potter?

- '[Albus](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/albus)' means white
- '[Dumbledore](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dumbledore)' is a type of bee

What is this representing?

Comment: Related but not a dup: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/30592/4918 "Name origins for characters in Harry Potter Series"

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The last name is actually not that fancy. As this old interview with Rowling states:

> How did you decide what to name your characters and places?
>
> I collect unusual names. I have notebooks full of them. Some of the names I made up, like Quidditch, Malfoy. Other names mean something -- ***Dumbledore, which means "bumblebee" in Old English...seemed to suit the headmaster, because one of his passions is music and I imagined him walking around humming to himself.*** And so far I have got names from saints, place-names, war memorials, gravestones. I just collect them -- I am so interested in names.

([Barnes and Nobles Interview with J.K. Rowling (1999)](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/0399-barnesandnoble.html); Emphasis mine)

Answer (score 17):

**Albus**

As you state, Albus translates to "white", which was a nod to alchemy:

> Colours also played their part in the naming of Hagrid and Dumbledore, whose first names are Rubeus (red) and Albus (white) respectively. **The choice was a nod to alchemy,** which is so important in the first Harry Potter book, where 'the red' and 'the white' are essential mystical components of the process. **The symbolism of the colours in this context has mystic meaning, representing different stages of the alchemic process** (which many people associate with a spiritual transformation). Where my two characters were concerned, I named them for the alchemical colours to convey their opposing but complementary natures: red meaning passion (or emotion); **white for asceticism;** Hagrid being the earthy, warm and physical man, lord of the forest; **Dumbledore the spiritual theoretician, brilliant, idealised and somewhat detached.** Each is a necessary counterpoint to the other as Harry seeks father figures in his new world.
>
> [Colours by J.K. Rowling](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/colours)

**Dumbledore**

J.K. Rowling just imagined him as such:

> How did you decide what to name your characters and places?
>
> I collect unusual names. I have notebooks full of them. Some of the names I made up, like Quidditch, Malfoy. Other names mean something -- Dumbledore, which means "bumblebee" in Old English...seemed to suit the headmaster, because one of his passions is music and **I imagined him walking around humming to himself.** And so far I have got names from saints, place-names, war memorials, gravestones. I just collect them -- I am so interested in names.
>
> [Barnes and Noble interview, March 19, 1999](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/1999/0399-barnesandnoble.html)

Answer (score 1):

Quote from Rowling herself:

> Many of the names are invented, for example "Quidditch" and "Muggle." I also collect unusual names, and I take them from all sorts of different places. "Hedwig" was a saint, "Dumbledore" is an old English word for "bumblebee," and "Snape" is the name of a place in England.

Albus is also interesting.  It's probable she just liked the word; Albus might have something to do with white=good.  It also could be a reference to Gandalf the White.  Albus can also mean wise, and could be a reference to Merlin (Albion).

Percival is the name of Albus's father.  No idea where Wulfric and Brian are from.

Comment: This is the same as another answer

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil When I began writing it it wasn't...it does have a few points that are not the same.  Would you like me to delete it?

Comment: Fair enough, if you didn't notice